# ebay api error Uploaded picture has unsupported file format

Tags: flutter, image-uploading, ebay-api

I am trying to upload an image as a binary MIME attachment to ebays api UploadSiteHostedPictures.  I keep receiving the following error: Uploaded picture has an unsupported file format.  The image is a jpg but i have tried png, and that didn't work either.

I have gone through the ebay knowledgebase java and c# examples and i cannot understand where i am going wrong.

Here is where i am passing the image file.

```
List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

Header

```
Map<String, String> uploadPictureHeader = {'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME': 'UploadSiteHostedPictures', 'X-EBAY-API-SITEID': '0', 'X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING': 'XML', 
                                              'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL': '967', 'X-EBAY-API-DETAIL-LEVEL': '0', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
                                              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=FormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'};
```

Body

```
String requestUploadedSiteHostedPicture = '''--FormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
                                                    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="XML Payload"

                                                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                                                    <UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
                                                        <RequesterCredentials>
                                                            <eBayAuthToken >$userTokenOAuth</eBayAuthToken>
                                                        </RequesterCredentials>
                                                        <PictureName>Vase</PictureName>
                                                        <PictureSet>Standard</PictureSet>
                                                        <ExtensionInDays>20</ExtensionInDays>
                                                    </UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>

                                                    --FormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
                                                    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Vase"; filename="Vase.jpg"
                                                    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

                                                    $base64Image

                                                    --FormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--''';
```

Making the call

```
final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: uploadPictureHeader,
      body: requestUploadedSiteHostedPicture,
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8")
    );
```

I have used online binary converters to convert the image as well, but that didn't work either.  Any help is much appreciated, thank you.